# Certificacion ssl en web local

Tags: php, ssl

actualmente tengo un sistema web en nube, el cual envía datos a un script local, estoy usando xampp, el script local envía esos datos a una impresora goDex, configurada en nuestra red local, por políticas CORS, no me permite enviar datos a ese script, por lo que viendo tutoriales y lecturas, llegue a la conclusión que al script local debería ponerle certificado ssl, debido a eso viene mi incógnita, ¿Cómo puedo comprar un certificado ssl para una web local y cual es el proceso para instalarlo y que sea valido para el navegador?
Si alguien tiene alguna idea o algún sitio donde pueda averiguar mas del tema lo agradecería.
Adjunto imagen de la arquitectura con la que trabajo:

[image: Imagen sacada de un video de YouTube de Willy Ruiz]

Comment: Quizá el primer paso sea poner tu red local bajo un nombre de dominio. Luego adquirir un certificado SSL para ese dominio, y ya a ver cómo lo instalas en XAMPP.

Comment: Interesante, investigaré en base a esa info.

Comment: @JoséCarlosPHP para poner la red local bajo el nombre de un dominio, lo hago desde apache.conf?

Comment: Puedes intentar crear un [certificado SSL autofirmado](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/azure/iot-hub/tutorial-x509-self-sign).

Comment: Por un lado tienes que hacer que el dominio apunte a esa IP, y por otro hacer que Apache atienda solicitudes para ese nombre de dominio, para esto te puede servir esta ayuda: https://manuais.iessanclemente.net/index.php/XAMPP_configuraci%C3%B3n_Servidor_Virtual_www.dominio.local#Configuraci.C3.B3n_servidor_virtual_web_Apache_en_XAMPP

Answer (score 0):

Let's encrypt es una iniciativa para que todas las páginas web dispongan de un certificado. Yo utilizo sus certificados en mis servidores Linux.

He encontrado el siguiente enlace, espero que te  sirva.

https://nefele.dev/blog/instalar-lets-encrypt-windows-bien-explicado/